# Remove NaN from pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

Is there a way to remove a NaN values from a panda series? I have a series that may or may not have some NaN values in it, and I'd like to return a copy of the series with all the NaNs removed.

Answer (score 129):

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,np.NaN,5,np.NaN])
>>> s[~s.isnull()]
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
5    5
```

**update** or even better approach as @DSM suggested in comments, using [`pandas.Series.dropna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
>>> s.dropna()
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
5    5
```

Answer (score 7):

A small usage of `np.nan ! = np.nan`

```
s[s==s]
Out[953]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
5    5.0
dtype: float64
```

---

More Info

```
np.nan == np.nan
Out[954]: False
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a pandas serie with NaN, and want to remove it (without loosing index):

> serie = serie.dropna()

```
# create data for example
data = np.array(['g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's']) 
ser = pd.Series(data)
ser.replace('e', np.NAN)
print(ser)

0      g
1    NaN
2    NaN
3      k
4      s
dtype: object

# the code
ser = ser.dropna()
print(ser)

0    g
3    k
4    s
dtype: object
```