# What is this 'nan' and how to get rid of it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have two DataFrames with multi indices, some of which are common to both data frames. I've been trying to extract numeric values from one column of one dataframe based on whether the index for this value exists in the second dataframe. It has been a major pain in the ass so far ..... So this is where I'm at right now:

```
a = []
b = []
for i in list:
    d = data.loc[i[0]].loc[i[1]].values[0]
    if i in another_list:
        a.append(d)
    else: 
        b.append(d)
```

Takes forever, but seems to be ok ... but now i need to do a t-test on those two lists ...
It turned out that some of the values are `nan`, which is probably why t-test also comes out as `nan`.
I have tried everything to get rid of them....
I tried putting `if isinstance(d, float)` and `if d != 'nan'` and `if d != np.NaN` into the loop, converting `float(data.loc[i[0]].loc[i[1]].values[0])`, doing `a = list(map(lambda x: round(float(x),2), a)), b = list(map(lambda x: round(float(x),2), b))` ... nothing works :( ... it's telling me that neither `nan`, nor `np.NaN` are in `a` or `b` so i don't know how to get rid of it.

I don't need to remove NaN from the DataFrame itself because that removes the rows too and I need that data, I just need to be able to do a t-test using values in one of its columns and `.dropna()` doesn't work on a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove NaN from pandas series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235401/remove-nan-from-pandas-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas `isnull` to handle the `nan`.

```
import pandas as pd

a = []
b = []
for i in list:
    d = data.loc[i[0]].loc[i[1]].values[0]
    if not pd.isnull(d): 
        if i in another_list:
            a.append(d)
        else: 
             b.append(d)
```

Comment: sweet baby geezus ... it works ... so many hours banging my head on the table ...
You're my hero.

Comment: I've been there mate.