# How to remove Empty Cell from data frame row wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have csv data in the following format

```
ab   aback  abandon  abate  Class
ab   NaN    abandon  NaN    A
NaN  aback  NaN      NaN    A
NaN  aback  abandon  NaN    B
ab   NaN    NaN      abate  C
NaN  NaN    abandon  abate  C
```

I want to remove the NaN cell and re-arrange the data as

```
ab  abandon A
aback   A   
aback   abandon B
ab  abate   C
abandon abate   C
```

The headers are not required in the processed form. I tried a number of threads such as [Remove NaN from pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235401/remove-nan-from-pandas-series), [Missing Data In Pandas Dataframes](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_missing_data.html%7Dhttps://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_missing_data.htm), [How can I remove Nan from list Python/NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011777/how-can-i-remove-nan-from-list-python-numpy) etc. but they are all providing column wise solution.

[here is the sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7PsfqmAuYkwcy1HRENrQjRDdlU/view?usp=sharing).
It has empty cells and when I display it using dataframe, all the empty cells are shown as NaN
Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ABRAR/Google Drive/Tourism Project/Small_sample.csv', low_memory=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Do you just want a list without the `NaN`s or do you want a dataframe? If you want a dataframe that second row is a problem since it only contains two elements. All the others have three elements.

Comment: The above output is required, not the dataframe. every structure will work for me. And do not consider the number of element in this sample. The actual file is having very large number of elements.

Comment: the Nan values can be removed but how is the restructuring working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Perennial for his suggestions above.  Finally, I did it as follows.

```
new_lines = []
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv:
    # skip the first line
    csv.readline()
    for line in csv.readlines():
        words = line.strip().split(',')
        new_words = [w for w in words if w and w.strip()]
        #skip the empty lines
        if len(new_words) != 0:
            new_lines.append(','.join(new_words))
df = pd.DataFrame(new_lines)
df.to_csv('results.csv', sep=',')
```

The @Scott's solution is elegant but I don't know, it always throws a memoryError exception.
One more thing, I do not want the row numbers in the resultant file. If anyone helps me out. Although, I delete that column using Excel :)

Answer (score 3):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x.values.astype(str)), axis=1)\
   .replace('nan','')

df = df.drop(df.index[df.eq('').all(axis=1)]) #drop all null rows

df = df.drop(df.columns[df.eq('').all()],axis=1) #drop all null columns

print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
         ab   aback
14    access        
18    accept        
23    access        
24      able  accept
47  accepted
```

Comment: can you please apply it to the file I attached in the original post? When I ran it, I am getting error message

Comment: @Abrar See edits... broke it up because I think you are trying go condense dataset by rows and columns.

Comment: @ Scott I have one issue that When I am using the original file, I am getting the memory error

Comment: Hrm...  May have to do it in two chunks or batches.  I'll see if I optimize this any.

Comment: Let's to to get rid of those all null rows after read_csv.... df = df[~df.isnull().all(axis=1)]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstand your objective, but something like this is easily done with some python code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

new_lines = []
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv:
    # skip the first line
    csv.readline()
    for line in csv.readlines():
        words = line.strip().split()
        new_words = [w for w in words if w != 'NaN']
        new_lines.append(' '.join(new_words))

for l in new_lines:
     print(l)
```

Comment: When I apply it on the file, I receive an output like this  , , , , , , ab, , , ,A

Comment: I used it on the pattern you showed on the question. Are you using an actual comma separated csv? In that case, please try with split(','). But for true csv, you are better off using the csv module.

Answer (score 0):

**`pandas`**

```
df.dropna(how='all').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), 1).fillna('')

            0           1
14     access            
18     accept            
23     access            
24       able      accept
47   accepted            
58       able  acceptable
60     access            
69  abundance            
78    academy            
87     access            
93     accept
```

---

**`numpy`**

```
v = df.values
i, j = np.where(df.notnull().values)
split_idx = np.where(np.append(False, i[1:] != i[:-1]))[0]
pd.DataFrame(np.split(v[i, j], split_idx), pd.unique(i)).fillna('')

            0           1
14     access            
18     accept            
23     access            
24       able      accept
47   accepted            
58       able  acceptable
60     access            
69  abundance            
78    academy            
87     access            
93     accept
```

---

**head spinning comprehension that I can't comprehend**

```
pd.DataFrame(*list(map(
            list,
            zip(*[(v[m], i) for v, m, i in
                  zip(df.values, df.notnull().values, df.index)
                  if m.any()])
        ))).fillna('')

            0           1
14     access            
18     accept            
23     access            
24       able      accept
47   accepted            
58       able  acceptable
60     access            
69  abundance            
78    academy            
87     access            
93     accept
```

**Timing**

```
%timeit df.dropna(how='all').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), 1).fillna('')
100 loops, best of 3: 7.21 ms per loop

%%timeit
v = df.values
i, j = np.where(df.notnull().values)
split_idx = np.where(np.append(False, i[1:] != i[:-1]))[0]
pd.DataFrame(np.split(v[i, j], split_idx), pd.unique(i)).fillna('')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop

%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(*list(map(
            list,
            zip(*[(v[m], i) for v, m, i in
                  zip(df.values, df.notnull().values, df.index)
                  if m.any()])
        ))).fillna('')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop

%%timeit
d1 = df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x.values.astype(str)), axis=1).replace('nan','')
d1 = d1.drop(d1.index[d1.eq('').all(axis=1)])
d1.drop(d1.columns[d1.eq('').all()],axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code drop a row if it contain some value (in this case, 'Amine'):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Name': ['Amine', 'Ali', 'Muhammad', 'Kareem',np.nan], 
        'Year': [2017, 2018,1995,2010,2018]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[df.Name != 'Amine']
```

Specifically: this will create a new DataFrame called 'df' that include all rows where the value of the cell in the 'Name' column does not equal 'Amine'

To delete rows that contain 'Nan' in some column, this code will be helpful:

```
df[pd.notnull(df.Name)]
```