# How do I print the not-NaN values only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering how to print out the values which are not NaN. I have seen many posts which try to count or sum the result, but I want to display it.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235401/remove-nan-from-pandas-series) is about how to remove NaN values. But I don't want to remove NaN values, just don't show them.

With this code:

```
import pandas as pd

birthday = pd.read_csv('birthday_data.csv')

print(birthday['BirthMonth'].notna())

if birthday['BirthMonth'].notna() == True:
    print(birthday['BirthMonth'])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: `birthday[birthday['BirthMonth'].notnull()]`?

Comment: You are comparing an entire series to `True`.  You want to mask your series with `notnull()`