# drop na for tuples in series Python

Tags: python, tuples, series, na

Let's say I have a series

```
 a = pd.Series([(1,2), (3,4), (float('NaN'),float('NaN'))])
```

How can I remove (nan,nan) from the series?

Regards,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove NaN from pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235401/remove-nan-from-pandas-series)

Comment: You want to remove those tuples that contain at leat one NaN? Just NaNs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to only keep pairs containing no NaN values, you can do:

```
a = a[~ a.apply(lambda x: np.isnan(x[0] or np.isnan(x[1])))]
```

Comment: All answers were good but this serves my purpose most! Thanks Serge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it via pandas, first filter an exploded dataframe

```
df[['x', 'y']] = pd.DataFrame(a.tolist(), index=a.index)  
df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
```

then back to list of tuples

```
new_tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Many good answers, but you can also try this:

```
pd.Series([(x,y) for (x,y) in a if ~np.isnan(x) and ~np.isnan(y)])
```